# Grails connecting to google cloud sql

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, google-cloud-sql

I'm new to Grails and I want to integrate it with my existing google cloud sql (Grails 2.x). What are the files i need to alter and are there any tutorials already ?

I was not able to find any. Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add your jdbc jar in your lib folder, and then configure the data source in your DataSource.groovy file:

for example:

```
 development {
    dataSource {
    dbCreate = "create"
    pooled = false // true doesn't work with Google SQL
    driverClassName = "com.google.cloud.sql.Driver" //<------THIS
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"//<------THIS
    username = 'root'
    password = ''
    url = 'jdbc:google:rdbms://yourinstancename/yourdatabasename'//<------THIS
 }
```

Comment: Just before getting your reply i tried with the usual mysql driver and gave it a try and it worked. I tried your code too and it worked awesome.Thanks a lot